# Batch Copy and Add to sub folder

Tags: batch-file

hope you can help me with this, i can't make it work what i need

I need to copy all the .pdf files from a source folder, create a folder with part of the name "T-123456" and add the respective PDF files found in the correct folder in the destination folder, but sometimes the name it varies or the reference change "SM17-123".

Example of files 
HC002T-1234562436787004332 
MV002T-1234562436787004332 
PP _002_T-123456_24_3678_7004332

Types of direfents files 
HC123CLG-32-172436787004259 
HC123SM17-1802436787004044

i have this code created but it makes part of the job because the name varies and create folders incorrect for that files, sometimes the files have more digits in the beggining example 001 or 0001, so i dont know how to omit the other references files and only work whith files "T-123456" also i need the batch continuously working for new files created in the source folder and if i have another routhe where i have other types of file and copy to the correct reference it would be great.

```
@echo off
title Electronic File

:loop
cls
timeout -t 1 >nul
color b
for %%A in (*.pdf) do (
   echo File Found %%A
   for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB
   for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%A") do set fextn=%%~xC
   for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%D in ("!fname:~5,8!") do set folname=%%D
   echo Name folder !folname!
   if not exist "!folname!" (
      echo Folder !folname! dont exist, creating
      md "!folname!" 2>nul
   ) else (
      echo Folder !folname! exists
   )
   echo Copying file %%A to folder !folname!
   xcopy "%%A" "!folname!"
   )

echo on

md "C:\test %All%"

xcopy /s /y "X:\test\pdf" "W:\Electronic File %All%"

goto :loop

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
for %%A in (*.pdf) do (
   echo File Found %%A
   set fname=%%~nA
   set fextn=%%~xA
   set folname=!fname:~5,8!
   ECHO !folname!|FINDSTR /i /r "[A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" >NUL
   IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO %%A - !folname! excluded
   ) ELSE (
    echo Name folder !folname!
    if not exist "!folname!" (
       echo Folder !folname! dont exist, creating
       ECHO md "!folname!" 2>nul
    ) else (
       echo Folder !folname! exists
    )
    echo Copying file %%A to folder !folname!
    ECHO xcopy "%%A" "!folname!"
   )
)
```

Here's the meat of the matter. `delayedexpansion` needs to be on - you don't show that in your original code.

Note that there is no requirement for `%%B`, `%%C`, `%%D` as within the loop, `%%A` contains the filename and hence you can `set` the variables from that name.

Note that `fextn` will apparently always be `.pdf` since that is the extension you specify in your filemask `*.pdf` so setting it seems superfluous.

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) may be used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

The change I've introduced is to `echo` the directoryname to `findstr`, searching `/i` case-insensitively for `/r` a regular-expression  which is one letter, a dash and then 6 numerics. If the directoryname matches then `errorlevel` will be set to `0` by `findstr`, otherwise, it will be set to `1`.

The `if errorlevel 1` means "if errorlevel is 1 or greater" and if that is so, the match was **UN**successful, so report the filename and extracted directoryname; otherwise, go through your logic (I've changed it to simply `echo` the `md` and `xcopy` commands, for testing).

---

Given that we now have a variable structure,

```
for %%A in (*.pdf) do (
   echo File Found %%A
   set "copied="
   set fname=%%~nA
   set fextn=%%~xA
   set folname=!fname:~5,8!
   ECHO !folname!|FINDSTR /i /r "[A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" >NUL
   IF not ERRORLEVEL 1 call :process "%%A"

   rem repeat this section for each match required - begin
   if not defined copied (
    set folname=!fname:~5,9!
    ECHO !folname!|FINDSTR /i /r "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]" >NUL
    IF not ERRORLEVEL 1 call :process "%%A"
   )
   rem repeat this section for each match required - end

   if not defined copied ECHO %%A - !folname! excluded
)
goto :eof

:process
echo Name folder %folname%
if not exist "%folname%" (
 echo Folder %folname% dont exist, creating
 ECHO md "%folname%" 2>nul
) else (
  echo Folder %folname% exists
)
echo Copying file %~1 to folder %folname%
ECHO xcopy "%~1" "%folname%"
set "copied=Y"
goto :eof
```

In your extended examples, it's not clear where the `PP` fits into the scheme.

The formula is reasonably simple. The start position is the first argument in the `set` (counting from first character=0) and the second the length to select. The `regex` match may be either a single character (matched literally) or [rangestart-rangeend] `.` matches any one character, so the first block I've shown selects from  `HC123CLG-32-172436787004259` from the 5th character (starting at 0) for 9 characters =`CLG-32-17` and matches this against alpha,alpha,alpha,-,numeric,numeric,-,numeric,numeric.

On a match, `errorlevel` is set to `0`, so the `:process` subroutine is `call`ed, with a parameter of `%%A` in quotes. The subroutine uses the value in `folname` and copies the file (name now in `%1` - `%~1` removes the quotes) as before.

So - it's as simple as repeating the block of code, altering the start and length of the string to be selected and changing the `regex` to suit the required pattern.

Comment: Great, tha help me a lot, another question is if i have more types of name files, how can i added to this code? HC123CLG-32-172436787004259
HC123SM17-1802436787004044 and with this code some files have HC0002T-1234562436787004332 one more number in the order of the file, so when the script start they omit this file but i need to do the same process

Comment: @WeFixIt: No idea, since you haven't specified what the destination directoryname is for each of your nominated files.

Comment: All the files are in the same directory, before that i move the folders to another directory.        
HC002***T-123456***2436787004332       
MV002***T-123456***2436787004332       
PP _002_***T-123456***_24_3678_7004332       
HC123***CLG-32-17***2436787004259        
HC123***SM17-18***02436787004044        
HC123***EVM-64-17***2436787004259       

Also in the same directory i have these other files      
F***T-123456*** and XML***T-123456***       

Sometimes the rules change because after the T- the numer of digits can be 3 or 4, i make it bold to the reference that only matters